# Execute query in parallel over a list of rows in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql, pyspark-pandas

In databricks I have N delta tables of stores with their products with this schema:

store_1:

| store | product | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prod 1 | abc |
| 1 | prod 2 | def |
| 1 | prod 3 | ghi |

store_2:

| store | product | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | prod 1 | abc |
| 2 | prod 10 | xyz |
| 2 | prod 23 | ghi |

I need to find every every identical product from the store 1 in the store 2, using the SKU column, so I'm running a query like this:

```
select * from df_store_1 st1 join df_store_2 st2 on st1.sku=st2.sku
```

That should return this product:

| product | sku |
| --- | --- |
| prod 1 | abc |

I need to do this for all the stores and products, and since I am a beginner with PySpark I was thinking to create a list of all the possible pairs of stores and traverse them like this:

```
list_dfs = []

for store1, store2 in list_all_pairs_stores:
   temp_df = spark.sql(“select st1.product, st2.product, st1.sku from store1 st1 join store2 st2 on st1.sku=st2.sku”).toPandas()
   list_dfs.append(temp_df)

all_equal_products = pd.concat(list_dfs, axis=1)
```

What would be an efficient way to parallelize these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating all possible pairs of stores, you can leverage the power of PySpark to perform the join operation on all pairs of stores in a single query.

Here is an example of how you can achieve this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Define a list of all the store names
store_names = ["store_1", "store_2", ... , "store_N"]

# Create a dictionary of dataframes, where the keys are the store names
store_dfs = {}
for store_name in store_names:
    store_dfs[store_name] = spark.table(store_name)

# Define a function to perform the join operation
def join_identical_products(store1, store2):
    return store_dfs[store1].join(store_dfs[store2], on="sku").select(col(store1+".product").alias(store1+"_product"), 
                                                                     col(store2+".product").alias(store2+"_product"), 
                                                                     col(store1+".sku"))

# Generate all pairs of stores
store_pairs = [(store1, store2) for i, store1 in enumerate(store_names) for store2 in store_names[i+1:]]

# Perform the join operation on all pairs of stores
all_equal_products = None
for store1, store2 in store_pairs:
    temp_df = join_identical_products(store1, store2)
    if all_equal_products is None:
        all_equal_products = temp_df
    else:
        all_equal_products = all_equal_products.union(temp_df)
```

Now in this case it defines a list of all the store names, and then creates a dictionary of `dataframes` where the keys are the store names. It then defines a function called `join_identical_products` which takes two store names as inputs and performs the join operation on the `sku` column.

Subsequently, it generates all possible pairs of stores using a list comprehension, and then iterates through each pair of stores, performing the join operation and adding the results to a single `dataframe` called `all_equal_products`.

Comment: it worked perfectly mate, thanks! How can I balance the number of queries running in parallel? The store_pairs and tables are very big and sometimes the script stops with this message: "The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached." @DipanjanMallick